# What mistakes did I make in writing tabs on redux? What do I need to change in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I implemented very simple tabs on the React.js.
You can see how it works in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tabs-redux-example-36psr
And my React code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const items = [{content:"London"}, {content:"Paris"}];

class Content extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
        <div>
        {this.props.content}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class Tabs extends React.Component {
    state = {
        active: 0
    }

   open = (e) => {
       this.setState({active: +e.target.dataset.index})
   }

    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            {this.props.items.map((n, i)=>
            <button data-index={i} onClick={this.open}>{n.content}</button>
            )}

       {this.props.items[this.state.active] && <Content {...this.props.items[this.state.active]} />}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Tabs items={items} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But now I started to study the Redux and so I decided to make these tabs on the Redux.But unfortunately my tabs on the editor do not work.

Code in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tabs-redux-example-ygg0f 
and I also write the code here:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {createStore} from "redux";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// action 
function changeTab (change){
    return{
        type: "CHANGE_TAB",
        change: change
    };
}

//Reducer
function reducer(state={someTab:{active: 0}},action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "CHANGE_TAB":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
           change: action.change
        });
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

// CombineReducer
const allReducers = combineReducers({
    oneReducer: reducer
});

// Tabs - main component

const items = [{content:"London"},{content:"Paris"}];

class Tabs extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            {this.props.items.map((n,i)=>
            <button data-index={i}  onClick={e => this.props.changeTab({this.props.someTab.active:+e.target.dataset.index})}>{n.content}</button>
            )}

            this.props.items[this.props.someTab.active] && <Content {...this.props.items[this.props.someTab.active]} />}
        </div>
        );
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      onOneReducer: state.oneReducer
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
     changeTab: () => dispatch(changeTab),
   };
}

connect(mapStateToProps,matchDispatchToProps)(Tabs);
    }
}

// Content - other component
class Content extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
          <div>
           {this.props.content}
          </div>
        );
    }
}


// index.js
const store = createStore(allReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider>
    <Tabs items={items} />
   </Provider>,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

What mistakes did I make in writing the code and how to fix them?

Comment: here `<button data-index={i}  onClick={e => this.props.changeTab({this.props.someTab.active:+e.target.dataset.index})}>{n.content}</button>`   `this.props.someTab.active` change it !

Comment: @adel How I will change it?

Comment: what you purpose of passing the object try changing it as normal parameter!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things you'll have to fix to get this working:

Syntax errors:

1. In `onClick`, `this.props.someTab.active:` should just be `active:`
2. `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect` should be moved outside the `Tabs` component
3. You're missing a `{` before `this.props.items[this.prop.someTab.active]`

Once you fix those, you'll still be getting a number of errors because you're trying to access properties of props that don't exist. `Tabs` isn't connected to the store, so the only props you have is `items`. Add `console.log(props)` on the first line of `render` in `Tabs` to see what I mean.

How to fix the Redux errors:

1. You need to pass your store into your Provider: `<Provider store={store}>`
2. You're calling connect, but not connecting your component to Redux. The fix:

```
class Tabs extends Component {...}

const ConnectedTabs = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Tabs);

...
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedTabs />
</Provider>
```

3. `mapStateToProps` should return an object whose properties correspond to the props your component expects, not the reducer name. In this case: `return { someTab: state.oneReducer.someTab }`

NOW you should see a page without errors. We aren't done yet though!

4. In `mapDispatchToProps` you need to call the function you're passing to `dispatch`, specifically call it with the argument you pass it in the component:

```
return { changeTab: change => dispatch(changeTab(change)) };
```

Or just use the object form of `mapDispatch`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { changeTab } // it works!
```

5. In your reducer, you're adding a `state.change` property, when you want to update `state.someTab.active`. You could either return `Object.assign({}, state, { someTab: { active: action.change.active } })`, or make it even simpler: get rid of references to `someTab` and just do `Object.assign({}, state, { active })`.

This should get you generally where you want to be.

Some suggestions for simplifying things:

1. You also really don't need multiple reducers at this point. You could really just pass `reducer` into `createStore`, and get rid of the references to `oneReducer`.
2. The only component method you're using is `render`, so you can use function components instead of class components. (`this.props` will just become `props`)
3. You don't need `data-index`, you can just do `onClick={() => props.changeTab({ active: i })}`

One other note: you can move `items` into the store. You'll still be able to access them via props, and all related state will be kept in one place, which is one of the advantages of Redux.

Good luck!